# Counting number of instances according to date difference (Excel/VBA)

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, vlookup, counting

I have the following data:

[Excel Table Screen Capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZM4wQ.png)

That is:

**Acquirer ID** ||| **Target ID** (not useful) ||| **Date**

123 ||| 456 ||| 20/01/2020

789 ||| 910 ||| 28/02/2019

I would like an additional column where for each acquirer I have a count of how many acquisitions it made in the past 3 years.
Therefore, for each acquirer ID with a given date, I need to count how many times that ID appears with a date less than 3 years distant from that date.

Thus if an acquirer made an acquisition in 2020, 2016, 2015 and 2014, in each instance, the count will amount to 0, 2, 1, 0 respectively for that given acquirer.

I have tried with COUNTIFS(), IF (), VLOOKUP(), but I could not get the result wanted as, once the condition is met, it sums all the IDs irrespective of the dates.

I also tried writing a Macro on VBA but my knowledge of the language is basically 0. I post the code in case it gives a better idea of the problem

```
Dim Sheet As Worksheet

Set dbs = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("db")

Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, count As Integer

lr = dbs.Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 
x = 0


For i = 2 To lr
    For j = i + 1 To lr
    Set myrange = Range("i:lr")
        If dbs.Cells(i, 4).Value - Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(dbs.Cells(i, 4).Value, myrange, 4, False) < 3 Then
        'I get a bug with Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup, it might be that an error must be dealt with in case of missing values
        count = count + 1
        End If
    Next j
Next i

dbs.Cells(i, 5).Value = count

End Sub
```

Any help is really appreciated, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Acquirer in A2:A10 and Dates in C2:C10, this formula goes in D2 and counts the number of records where all of the following are true:

- Acquirer ID is the same as A2
- Date is less than the date in C2
- Date is greater than or equal to 3 years before the date in C2

`=COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$10,A2,$C$2:$C$10,"<"&C2,$C$2:$C$10,">="&EDATE(C2,-36))`

[image]

Comment: Thank you! It works indeed.
I had tried some combinations with COUNTIFS( DATE.DIFF() ) but this would return only zeros